# How to get value by column name in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have one tab delimited file.

cat file

```
A      B     C
2      3     4 
3      4     5
2      6     6
```

infile<-read.table("file",header=TRUE)

I need to get value for column which has header = "A".

```
 A 
 2
 3
 2
```

How can i get it?

Comment: This is a *very* basic question. What have you tried? Did it work/not work/not do what you expected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a single column `data.frame` as the output:

```
infile["A"]
infile[1]
```

For a vector as the output:

```
infile[, "A"]
infile[, 1]
infile[["A"]]
infile[[1]]
infile$A
```

Answer (score 1):

infile$A should work. You need read R book more and then to start your programming trials.

Comment: Not *exactly*. This will result in a vector, not a single-column `data.frame`. But, maybe that's what the OP wants....